# With AlertDialog, how to align the top of the choice text with the checkbox?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-layout, kotlin-android-extensions

I am using setMultiChoiceItems of AlertDialog. The check mark is at the vertical center of the choice text. I would like it to be at the top. How to do that?

(Kotlin code. Java answers will be fine.)

```
        AlertDialog.Builder (this).run {
            val choices = arrayOf(
                "Option 1 is very long. It is more than 3 lines. I would like to align the text top with the check box top.",
                "Option 2 is very long. It is more than 3 lines. I would like to align the text top with the check box top.",
                "Option 3 is very long. It is more than 3 lines. I would like to align the text top with the check box top.",
           )
            val booleanSelections = booleanArrayOf(true, true, true)
            setMultiChoiceItems(choices, booleanSelections, null)
            show()
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed. This is a nuisance. Hope you get a solution. A frame around the items would be nice too.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom layout in this multichoice dialog like this.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(choice, 0, null);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                R.layout.item_text_layout, choices);
        builder.setAdapter(arrayAdapter, null);

AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

ListView listView = alertDialog.getListView();
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
            R.layout.item_text_layout, choices));
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) view;
            checkedItems[position] = !checkedTextView.isChecked();
        }
    });

alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            setCheckedItems(((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView());
        }
    });

alertDialog.show();
```

Then handle

Comment: If I correctly understand you are actually suggesting to create my own check items, ignoring this functionality of AlertDialog. So, 2 quesitons. One, where here is the actual alignment to top? Two, is this your suggestion because to your best knowledge there is no way to do to the alignment with the AlertDialog layout?

Comment: Have you tried this? Did you get the items  aligned properly?